# Symfony Form Model @Unique on new Email field

Tags: symfony, model-view-controller, annotations

Good evening,

i have added a form for changing the email of a user:

ChangeEmailFormType:

```
$builder->add('current_email', 'email', array(
        'label' => 'profile.changePassOrEmail.emailLbl',
        'translation_domain' => 'Startup',
        'mapped' => false,
        'attr'   => array(
            'readonly' => true,
            'value' => $this->user->getEmail()
        )
    ))
    ->add('new_email', 'repeated', array(
        'type' => 'email',
        'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'Startup'),
        'first_options' => array('label' => 'profile.changePassOrEmail.newEmail'),
        'second_options' => array('label' => 'profile.changePassOrEmail.newEmail2'),
        'invalid_message' => 'profile.changeEmail.mismatch',
    ))
```

For the 'new_email' i generated a Form Model Class as the following:

```
class ChangeEmail
{
/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Email()
 */
public $new_email;
}
```

My Controller is the following to create the Form and process it:

```
  */
public function changeEmailAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }


    $form_email = $this->createForm(new ChangeEmailFormType($user));
    $form_email->setData(new ChangeEmail());

    $form_email->handleRequest($request);

    if($form_email->isValid())
    {
    }else{
    }

    return $this->render(
        'UserBundle:ChangeEmail:changeEmail.html.twig',
        array(
            'form_email' => $form_email->createView()
        )
    );
}
```

This all works fine, but i've got a problem with my "ChangeEmail" class.
I don't know how to add there the "@Unique" Annotation to the $new_email field.
How can i check there on the database or even create a custom annotation for checking if the
email already exists on my usertable? In the registration form, FosUserBundle handles that.

Regards and thanks.

Comment: here - http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html

Comment: "Validates that a particular field (or fields) in a Doctrine entity is (are) unique. "

As you can see, this is not a doctrine entity. It is a Form Model Class for handling the submission. Like FosUserBundle is doing it with the Change Password functionality.

Comment: You are posting a link that does not relate to my question and to the real question, you are not answering :'D

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I've written my own validator and binded it to the new_email field.